# Itextsharp: NO break for pdfPcell

Tags: itext

I have a Table made of many PdfPcell like this:

```
enter code cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(txt0, myfontB))
                        cell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5f5"))
                        cell.PaddingTop = 15
                        cell.PaddingBottom = 15
                        cell.Border = 0
                        cell.Colspan = 2
                        tablegg.AddCell(cell)



                        cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(txt1, myfontN))
                        cell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5f5"))
                        cell.PaddingTop = 15
                        cell.PaddingBottom = 5
                        cell.Border = 0
                        cell.Colspan = 2
                        tablegg.AddCell(cell) here
```

My problem it's, where txt1 is long the PdfPcell is wrote directly next page, instead to continue part on first page and the rest on next page.
Any suggestion how to fix it?

Tks
V

Comment: Consider setting the `SplitLate` property

Comment: @mkl it works tks

Comment: Would you make that an actual answer or shall I?

Comment: yes actual answer!

Comment: Actually I stumbled across an answer here which already explains the behavior. I vote this question to be a duplicate of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [table row is getting started from the new page in itext pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063845/table-row-is-getting-started-from-the-new-page-in-itext-pdf)

Comment: @mkl I fixed the problem with your first answer, splitlate works!